# How do I work on raytracing an image concurrently in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

For example: if I have an image 256x256, how would I run all of the 8x8 (32 threads) sections in parallel with a set of loops like so:

```
for y = 1:height
 for x = 1:length
... and so on
```

Comment: how does this relate to ray-tracing? could you provide more background info on that? Also refer to the [Multi-Threading](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/#Setup-1) section in the doc and [TiledIteration.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/TiledIteration.jl) package as an example.

Comment: I'm relating the problem back to raytracing; where you iterate through every pixel on the surface.